# appolo useMutation array of object

Tags: firebase, react-native, graphql

I try to make mutation with appolo, but I don't know what's the problem.

Everything work in the playground.

```js
const ADD_PURCHASE = gql`
  mutation addPurchaseById($data: {uniqueId: String, items: [{price: Int, name: String, description: String, image: String}]}) {
    addPurchaseById(data: $data) {
      price
      name
      image
      description
    }
  }
`;
```

```js
const [addPurchaseById, {data, loading}] = useMutation(ADD_PURCHASE);
```

here, my `cart` is an array of object: name, price, description, image.
This is how I try to make the request:

```js
const uniqueId = getUniqueId();
await addPurchaseById({
   variables: {data: {uniqueId: uniqueId, items: cart}},
});
```

On my server part, I have this in my typeDefs :

```
input ItemMutation {
        price: Float!
        name: String!
        image: String!
        description: String!
    }

    input Purchase {
        uniqueId: String!
        items: [ItemMutation]!
    }

    type Mutation {
        addPurchaseById(data: Purchase!): [Item]!
    }
```

Comment: `mutation addPurchaseById($data: Purchase!) {`

Comment: thank you very much!!

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables